# ProcessLookupError: Could not attach to RPC process by querying 'proc.net_connections()'

Tags: web3.py, brownie

Anyone know the solution to this?

```
root@DESKTOP-MIQQV4H:/mnt/c/users/user/documents/Blockchain/brownie_fund_me# brownie run scripts/deploy.py
Brownie v1.17.2 - Python development framework for Ethereum

BrownieFundMeProject is the active project.
  File "brownie/_cli/__main__.py", line 64, in main
    importlib.import_module(f"brownie._cli.{cmd}").main()
  File "brownie/_cli/run.py", line 44, in main
    network.connect(CONFIG.argv["network"])
  File "brownie/network/main.py", line 48, in connect
    rpc.attach(host)
  File "brownie/network/rpc/__init__.py", line 113, in attach
    pid = self._find_rpc_process_pid(resolved_addr)
  File "brownie/network/rpc/__init__.py", line 194, in _find_rpc_process_pid
    return self._get_pid_from_net_connections(laddr)
  File "brownie/network/rpc/__init__.py", line 234, in _get_pid_from_net_connections
    raise ProcessLookupError(
ProcessLookupError: Could not attach to RPC process by querying 'proc.net_connections()'
```

Have tried:

python 3.8
making exception in firewall
ganache-cli & ganache desktop app seperately

Also, I went back to the repository of the previous lesson to check if that code would still deploy. However, it gives the same error, while it did work when I was running it earlier. Must I have installed something that messed it up?

**update

```
networks:
  development:
    verify: False
  rinkeby:
    eth_usd_price_feed: 0x8A753747A1Fa494EC906cE90E9f37563A8AF630e
    verify: True
```

This is how the network config looks at this point in the video, so no default just yet.

So now I added

```
default: development
```

But still the same problem.

** update

Still no solution. When I look in ganache however, I do get this interaction. So it does seem like something is happening.[image]

Comment: What is your default network in your brownie config? Can you add that to your question?

Comment: When I have ganache-cli or ganache UI running I get this error.

Comment: Wait, are you running ganache at the same time?

Comment: What happens when you just fork the repo and run from scratch

Comment: Ill try and do that. In the tutorial it is specifically said I need to have ganache running in the background. So do I need to, or do I not?